# one geofences for multiple markers

Tags: android, location

I am developing android application which is tracking multiple user locations.

I want to create a function to checking multiple locations. 
1. First build geofences according to one of user locations.
2. Checking is there any locations that outside the created geofences.
3. Function will return true or false according to condition on number 2.

Is there any API or service i can use to make explained function above.

Thank you, your help really matter for me

Comment: You should write about the functioning of an idea or a thought.

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. i made a revision on my question, thanks for your respond